# How to open material design menu on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I, am using material design lite to create the menu. As per the documentation the menu open on click on the icon. However, I need to open the menu on mouse hover

Here is the code for the menu

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button id="demo-menu-lower-left" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
      <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
    </button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-left">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

Also, can anyone let me know how can I create mega menu as in this [link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-slide-down-on-hover-with-carousel) using **Material Design Lite**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For menu click event is already written so you can use same event on mouse over and out. See updated button element.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<button id="demo-menu-lower-left" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" onmouseover="this.click()" onmouseout="this.click()">
      <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
    </button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-left">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
  <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

Move mouse over and out event to javascript functions to get more control.

**Note:** I am not UI developer, so it may not be best solution.

Comment: Can you also tell me how can I create mega menu using MDL.

Comment: I don't know MDL but I think for mega menu, you can use div instead of ul and use that div for your menu design.